# Arduino, Ethernet.begin(mac) prevent led high

Tags: arduino

I got an odd problem and i'm not sure what is causing it.
Maybe one of you can can see what i'm doing wrong.

The problem is the function Ethernet.begin(mac) - It prevent the LED from turning on, when the button is pressed.

Ethernet is included, because I need to use it later.
I just changed the code, to make it easier to locate the error.

It works fine if I disable Ethernet.begin(mac)

This is my code:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
//byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 1, 104 };
char server[] = "b2b.as";

// constants won't change. They're used here to
// set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 2;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int ledPin =  13;      // the number of the LED pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void setup()
{

  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

  //Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(1000);

  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  Serial.println();

}

void loop() {
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
  // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    // turn LED on:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  } else {
    // turn LED off:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the declaration of your `Ethernet`?

Comment: what do you mean? am i missing something?

Comment: what model of arduino you're using?

Comment: Uno with lan shield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon reading at the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/ethernet)
The shield will communicate with Arduino using the digital pins `11,12 & 13`.
In which your `ledPin` is connected to digital pin `13`. I think that causes the issue if you started your `Ethernet` using `.begin` which will caused pin `13` to be unavailable since it will be used by the `Ethernet`. Follow the pin assignment for the shield and transfer your `ledPin` from a different digital pin available

**Note: This is for Arduino UNO ONLY**

Comment: You are correct, thats why it works when Ethernet.begin() is disabled... I feel so stupid now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @KennethPoulsen not a problem, you can mark it correct if it fixes your issue so others may confirm in the future that it is the fixed :)

Comment: I forgot about that, it has been marked as correct :)

Comment: @KennethPoulsen awesome! Thanks :)